# Getting all events of a Control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, reflection

I am trying to get all events information concerning a specific control.
For this purpose, I wrote a snippet of code that works if I hard code the class name, But when I try to make it dynamic it fails, That is it doesn't give any error, but instead, the events collection becomes null.
This is the code that works :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve;

var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(typeof(DataGridView).Module.FullyQualifiedName);
var events = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(typeof(DataGridView).AssemblyQualifiedName, false, true).GetEvents();
```

And this is the counter part that fails:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve;
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(cmbox.SelectedItem.GetType().Module.FullyQualifiedName);
var events = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(cmbox.SelectedItem.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName, false, true).GetEvents();
```

this `ComboBx` is filled with windows form controls like this :

```
var controlType = typeof(Control);
            var controls = controlType
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => controlType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                            t.Namespace == "System.Windows.Forms"
                );
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                cmbox.Items.Add(control);
            }
```

And by the way this is the event handlers content :

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
      return System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);  
}
```

So what am I missing here? how to get around this ?

Comment: Why would some one give me donw vote for Gods sake !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
var events = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(cmbox.SelectedItem.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName, 
             false, true).GetEvents();
```

it returns `System.RuntimeType`

whereas when you explictly call `typeof(DataGridView)` it generates it's full assembly qualified name.

One workaround I found is by using **dynamic** keyword

here it is

```
        dynamic controltype = cmbx.SelectedItem;
        var events = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(controltype.AssemblyQualifiedName, false, true).GetEvents();
        foreach (var item in events)
        {

        }
```